# Read multiple values from file with fstream?

Tags: c++, stream, fstream

Can I read multiple values from tab separated text file with

```
double value1, value2, value3;
ifstream in;
fin.open ("myfile.dat", ifstream::in);
fin >> value1 >> value2 >> value3;
```

I get zeros in all values.

Comment: `ofstream::in` is a nice one...

Comment: Have you checked if your `ifstream` encountered an error?

Comment: Sorry forgot how cruel C++ is.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in your code there are three important mistakes:

- `fin` was not declared in this scope (you probably need to change the `in` at the second line to `fin`)
- `ofstream::in` does not exist, you probably mean `fstream::in`
- you should also make sure that your input file exist. This can be done with `fin.good()`

Comment: Of course `ofstream::in` exists - the `openmode` enumeration is defined in `ios_base` which is a base of all the `iostream` classes.

Comment: `fin.good()` isn't a good choice.  This is one of the rare cases where it will probably work (but I think it can still return `false` if the file is empty).  But since in general, the choice of `fin.good()` is a flag that the programmer doesn't know iostreams, I'd avoid it even here.  (To test if the open succeeded, I like `fin.is_open()`, since it says exactly what you're testing.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

main.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  double value1, value2, value3;
  std::ifstream fin;
  fin.open ("myfile.dat", std::ifstream::in);
  if (fin.good()) {
    fin >> value1 >> value2 >> value3;
    printf("%f, %f, %f\n", value1, value2, value3);
  }
}
```

myfile.dat:

```
3.4893289   1.328923    3.432901
```

Output:

```
3.4893289, 1.328923, 3.432901
```

I hope this helps.